# How can I SELECT multiple values from 5 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to SELECT PROJECT_ID, STAFF_ID, HARDWARE_ID and SOFTWARE_ID which are all linked in a table ASSIGNMENTS, but I want to show that link while also showing all the attributes in each respective table linked to the relevant ID (e.g STAFF_NAME, JOB_TYPE, JOB_GRADE from the STAFF table). Here is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE PROJECT
(PROJECT_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_NAME CHAR(20),
PROJECT_TYPE CHAR(20),
START_DATE DATE,
END_DATE DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (PROJECT_ID));

CREATE TABLE HARDWARE
(HARDWARE_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
HARDWARE_NAME CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (HARDWARE_ID));

CREATE TABLE SOFTWARE
(SOFTWARE_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
SOFTWARE_NAME CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (SOFTWARE_ID));

CREATE TABLE STAFF
(STAFF_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
STAFF_NAME CHAR(20),
JOB_TYPE CHAR(20),
JOB_GRADE CHAR(20),
PRIMARY KEY (STAFF_ID));

CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENTS
(ASSIGNMENT_ID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_ID CHAR(5),
STAFF_ID CHAR(5),
HARDWARE_ID CHAR(5),
SOFTWARE_ID CHAR(5),
PRIMARY KEY (ASSIGNMENT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (PROJECT_ID) REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (STAFF_ID) REFERENCES STAFF(STAFF_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (HARDWARE_ID) REFERENCES HARDWARE(HARDWARE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (SOFTWARE_ID) REFERENCES SOFTWARE(SOFTWARE_ID));
```

Here is some basic data:

```
INSERT INTO PROJECT (PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_TYPE, START_DATE, END_DATE)
VALUES ('B0001','BIKESHOP.COM','WEB DEVELOPMENT',TO_DATE('15/01/17','DD/MM/YY'),TO_DATE('15/02/17','DD/MM/YY'));

INSERT INTO HARDWARE (HARDWARE_ID, HARDWARE_NAME)
VALUES ('H0001','WEBDEV PC1');

INSERT INTO SOFTWARE (SOFTWARE_ID, SOFTWARE_NAME)
VALUES ('S0001','COFFEECUP IDE');

INSERT INTO STAFF (STAFF_ID, STAFF_NAME, JOB_TYPE, JOB_GRADE)
VALUES ('ST001','JOHN MASON','WEB DEVELOPER','1');

INSERT INTO ASSIGNMENTS (ASSIGNMENT_ID, PROJECT_ID, STAFF_ID, HARDWARE_ID, SOFTWARE_ID)
VALUES ('A0001','B0001','ST001','H0001','S0001');
```

I have used this code to get a PROJECT_ID linked to multiple STAFF_ID values with STAFF_NAME also given:

```
SELECT STAFF.STAFF_ID, STAFF.STAFF_NAME, ASSIGNMENTS.PROJECT_ID
FROM ASSIGNMENTS 
INNER JOIN STAFF ON ASSIGNMENTS.STAFF_ID = STAFF.STAFF_ID 
WHERE ASSIGNMENTS.PROJECT_ID = 'B0001';
```

But how can I SELECT all attributes from all tables linked to a single PROJECT_ID?

Comment: Select * from...  Etc?

Comment: one SELECT statement can have multiple JOIN clauses. starting from your existing code (last snippet in OP) add joins for the other related tables by their primary key/foreign key relation.

Comment: Just like the inner join on Staff, join the rest of the tables you need using the appropriate foreign keys and add the required attributes to the select. What seems to be the problem or confusion?

Comment: I should mention I'm new to SQL Developer and I was given the code for joining PROJECT_ID to STAFF_ID from a fellow user here, but I don't understand it well enough yet to amend the code above to get the desired result. If I could see the code myself I would be able to understand how it works from reading it, but as it stands now I don't know how to make the above code work for this query.

Answer (score 0):

A big join like this:

```
Select s.staff_name,
H.Hardware_name,
Sf.Software_name,
P.Project_name,
P.Project_type --you get the idea. Select other columns if you need
From assignments a
Inner join staff s on a.staff_id = s.staff_id
Inner join software sf on a.software_id = sf.software_id
Inner join hardware h on a.hardware_id = h.hardware_id
Inner join project p on a.project_id = p.project_id
Where a.project_id = 'A0001';
```